# Is rsync efficient at copying files that grow from the middle?

Tags: backup, rsync, database-backups

Suppose I have a file of size n, which has been replicated to another location with rsync.

```
Source
|-------------------------|
0                         n

Destination
|-------------------------|
0                         n
```

In the source file, s bytes are inserted at position i.

```
Source
|----------|-----|--------------|
0   Same   i    i+s    Same    n+s

Destination
|----------|--------------|
0   Same   i     Same     n
```

Does rsync generally avoid copying the range i+s...n+s since it's the same as i...n in the destination?

If so, what are the limits on i and s before rsync has to copy a significant amount (or all of) i+s...n+s?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes" rsync does mostly avoid copying the range i+s to n+s.  It breaks up the file on the sending side into blocks and calculates a checksum for each block.  Then it iterates over the receiver side file using a [rolling checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash).  That way if the block that exists on the sender side exists anywhere on the receiver side it won't be copied again.

This allows the offset (i+s .. i+n) between blocks to be any size.  The only data in the range i+s to n+s that would be copied again is the data inside a block that has been modified.  Thus the re-copied data is a function of your block size, which is dependent on [file size](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2001-November/000595.html) if you don't specify it using --block_size.  The worst case if you insert data in one location is that two blocks mostly containing data that exists on the receiver side already are copied over.

Comment: What if s%block size > 0 and the blocks don't align for i+s..n+s? Edit: never mind, the rolling checksum covers any alignment.

Comment: Right, the only thing s%block size != 0 affects is whether you have to re-transmit data that is in blocks on the edge of the new data.